# How can I force emacs (or any editor) to read a file as if it is in ASCII format?

Tags: emacs, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I could not find this answer in the `man` or `info` pages, nor with a search here or on Google.  I have a file which is, in essence, a text file, but it somehow got screwed up upon saving.  (I think there are a few strange bytes at the front of the file accidentally.)

I am able to open the file, and it makes sense, using `head` or `cat`, but not using any sort of editor.

In the end, all I wish to do is open the file in emacs, delete the "messy" characters, and save it once cleaned up.  The file, however, is ***huge***, so I need something powerful like emacs to be able to open it.

Otherwise, I suppose I can try to create a script to read this in line by line, forcing the script to read it in text format, then write it.  But I wanted something quick, since I won't be doing this over & over.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Did you try using Emacs.? Did you get any errors? Generally Emacs by default does decent job in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the file using [hexl-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html), which lets you edit the file in hexadecimal. That would let you see precisely what those offending characters are, and remove them.

It sounds like you either got a different line ending in the file (eg: carriage returns on a *nix system) or it got saved in an unexpected encoding.

Comment: yeah, it somehow got saved in unicode UTF-16 format, with a little endian prefix.  (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark  )  "Fixed" it -- hack job -- by just removing those first 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i.bk -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g;' file
```

Found this perl one liner here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=619792

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd>`find-file-literally` in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strings` to grab "printable characters in file". You might have to play with the `--encoding` though I have only ever used it to grab ascii strings from executable files.